# IE 11 is not rendering attributes from en.yml ruby file located at config\locales location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the below Ruby code in an .erb file.

`<%= label(:product_details_labels, :product_name) %>`

The labels are defined in `en.yml` file located at `config\locales

But the values for these labels are not getting rendered in IE 11 browser and instead I see the label name **product_name** displayed in the website.

This issue is only happening in IE 11 and works fine in IE 9 and Chrome, Firefox browsers.

Any reason why its not rendering in IE11?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken maybe there is a compatibility option on IE, have you tried that? Also, check the metatag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` I'm not sure this will fix, it is just a guess =)

Comment: It sounds like it's not able to determine the language from the browser. Have you checked the browser settings or tried this with IE 11 on another computer?